# Why does a hidden input lose my view model's property value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I use the following Razor markup to try and send my `PageCount` value to the client, the value of the input is rendered as 0:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "search-form" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PageCount)
```

This renders as follows, despite `PageCount` having a value of 2:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PageCount must be a number." data-val-required="The PageCount field is required." id="PageCount" name="PageCount" type="hidden" value="0">
```

When I fall right back on nearly all plain ol' HTML, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PageCount" id="PageCount" value="2">
```

Is there some funny behaviour with Razor w.r.t. hidden inputs, or what?

Comment: Please post your get action method code that populates the data in your model for the view.  Also, what was the code you used to generate `<input type="hidden" name="PageCount" id="PageCount" value="2">`?

Comment: @Gromer, I hand coded that because generated code appeared to be broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you setting the `PageCount` value in your POST controller action? If so make sure you have removed the old value from the ModelState:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SomeViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("PageCount");
    model.PageCount = 2;
    return View(model);
}
```

The reason for this is that HTML helpers use the initially POSTed value when binding, not the one from the model. So you should remove the old value from the ModelState if you intend to modify it in your controller action.

And that's not only limited to HiddenFor helper. It's how all HTML helpers that generate input fields work.

Comment: Yes, I am setting it in POST! It's a search action, and everything except a small shim in GET, is set in POST. I've never come across this caveat before. Thanks!